# lightweight data structure for java google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a google app engine based app which stores data in the datastore.  I want to implement a cron that will read around 20k rows of data each day and summarize the data into a much smaller data set and store it in a lightweight, easy to access data structure that I will use later to serve google charts to users.

I think it will be much too costly to read all the instance level data every time a user needs the chart, therefore I want to compile the data "ahead of time" once per day.

I'm thinking of the following options and I'm interested in any feedback or approaches that would optimize performance and minimize GAE overhead.

Options:

1)  Create a small csv or xml file and keep it locally on the server, then read the data from there

2)  Persist another "summary level" object in the data store and read that (still might be costly?)

3)  Create the google chart SVG and store it locally then re-serve it to users (not sure if this is possible)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check, but I think datastore + memcache may endup being the cheapest one.

In your cronjob you precompute the data you need to return for each graph and store it in both datastore and memcache.

For each graph request you get the data from memcache.
Memcache data can however be deleted at any time, so if not available there you read it from datastore and put it back into memcache.

Answer (score 0):

Why not generate the "expensive" data for the first request, then store those results in [memcache](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/)? Depending on your particular implementation, even the first, expensive request might be slightly cheaper than reading & parsing local files. Subsequent reads will hit your memcache and be much cheaper all around.

Comment: Looks very promising.  I had a feeling there was a good option I was missing!